# How to enable ping between machines connected in two interfaces?

Tags: iptables, nat, ethernet

I have a linux board with two ethernet interfaces as mentioned below.

- eth0 connected to another linux machine (ad-hoc)
- eth0 on board 191.168.1.2 connected to Linux machine 192.168.1.3
- eth1 on board 10.222.190.25 connected to router 10.222.190.1

I want to enable the ping from linux machine (192.168.1.3) towards router 10.222.190.1. Basically I want the traffic to be passed through the board and then towards router.

I believe by setting the correct ipables and NAT rules we should be able to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

This would normally involve neither `iptables` nor NAT, unless NAT is actually what you want, but that's a separate question, and not the "normal" way to achieve connectivity between IP networks.

You need 3 things:

- 192.168.1.3 needs to be told how to reach 10.222.190.25. If 192.168.1.3 has no other type of connectivity, you can achieve this by simply setting 192.168.1.3's default route to 192.168.1.2.
- The box you intend to use as a router has to have routing enabled. Enable it like this:

  ```
  echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding
  ```

  How you make that persistent across reboots is distribution-dependent.
- 10.222.190.1 needs to be told how to reach 192.168.1.3. There, you should add a static route to the 192.168.1.0 pointing to 10.222.190.25. Be sure to get the prefix length of the 192.168.1.0 subnet right. You didn't specify what you used, but you probably used /24.